# How to pass command line to save into list

Tags: python, argv, sys

How to pass command line to save into list

Disclaimer Please dont say `print (ARGV1[0])`

```
import sys
ARGV1 = []
for ARGV in sys.argv[2:]:
    ARGV1.append(sys.argv[2:])
print (ARGV1)
```

My Out

```
[['2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4']]
```

My Expected out

['2', '3', '4']

Disclaimer Please dont say `print (ARGV1[0])`

Comment: `ARGV1 = sys.argv[2:]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
ARGV1 = sys.argv[2:]
```

Since you have 3 values in input its adding same list 3 times.